# Make SWT Labels not inherit the Alpha of the shell

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, label, alpha

I'm trying to make a small clock that has a translucent background but fully opaque numbers. Any use of the `setAlpha()` method causes the shell and everything in it to become translucent. Is there a way, in SWT, to force the labels to have Alpha = 255 even if the Alpha of the Shell = 100? If not, is there a way to do so in some other relatively simple GUI library?

```
public class SystemClock {
    Label labelHours;
    Label labelMinutes;
    Label labelSeconds;
    Label labelMeridian;
    boolean pause = false;
    Display display;
    Runnable repeat = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
                if( !shlClock.isDisposed())
                    pullClock();
                    display.timerExec( 1000, this );
        }
    };
    protected Shell shlClock;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SystemClock window = new SystemClock();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void open() {
        display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shlClock.open();
        shlClock.layout();
        repeatClock();
        while (!shlClock.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void createContents() {
        shlClock = new Shell(SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.ON_TOP);
        shlClock.setModified(true);
        shlClock.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);
        shlClock.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.keyCode == SWT.ESC){
                    System.exit(0);
                }else if(e.keyCode == 80 || e.keyCode == 112){
                    pause = !pause;
                        if(pause){
                            display.timerExec(-1,repeat);
                        }else{
                            display.timerExec(100,repeat);
                        }
                }
            }
        });
        shlClock.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(0, 0, 0));
        shlClock.setSize(95, 25);
        shlClock.setAlpha(180);
        shlClock.setLocation((1366-95),250);
        shlClock.setText("Clock");
        shlClock.setLayout(null);

        Region overShell = new Region();
        Region minuteShell = new Region();
        Region hoursShell = new Region();
        Region secondShell = new Region();
        Region colon1Shell = new Region();
        Region colon2Shell = new Region();
        Region meridianShell = new Region();

        Rectangle overShellRec = new Rectangle(0,0,95,25);
        Rectangle overShellRecSub = new Rectangle(2,2,91,21);
        Rectangle innerRec = new Rectangle(5,5,86,16);


        overShell.add(overShellRec);
        overShell.subtract(overShellRecSub);
        overShell.add(innerRec);

        shlClock.setRegion(overShell);
        Rectangle size = overShell.getBounds();
        shlClock.setSize(size.width, size.height);

        Label labelColonHoursMinutes = new Label(shlClock, SWT.ALPHA);
        labelColonHoursMinutes.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        labelColonHoursMinutes.setBounds(20, 5, 3, 15);
        labelColonHoursMinutes.setText(":");

        Label labelColonMinutesSeconds = new Label(shlClock, SWT.ALPHA);
        labelColonMinutesSeconds.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        labelColonMinutesSeconds.setBounds(41, 5, 3, 15);
        labelColonMinutesSeconds.setText(":");

        labelMinutes = new Label(shlClock, SWT.NONE);
        labelMinutes.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        labelMinutes.setBounds(26, 5, 14, 12);
        labelMinutes.setText("00");

        labelHours = new Label(shlClock, SWT.RIGHT);
        labelHours.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        labelHours.setBounds(5, 5, 14, 12);
        labelHours.setText("00");

        labelSeconds = new Label(shlClock, SWT.NONE);
        labelSeconds.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        labelSeconds.setBounds(47, 5, 14, 12);
        labelSeconds.setText("00");

        labelMeridian = new Label(shlClock, SWT.NONE);
        labelMeridian.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        labelMeridian.setBounds(65, 5, 21, 12);
        labelMeridian.setText("AM");

    }


public void pullClock(){
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int hours;
        int minutes;
        int seconds;
        String hoursStr;
        String minutesStr;
        String secondsStr;
        String meridian;            
            currentTime/=1000;
            seconds = (int)currentTime%60;
            currentTime/=60;
            minutes = (int)currentTime%60;
            currentTime/=60;
            hours = (int)currentTime%24;
            hours -=4;

            switch(hours){
                case -4: hoursStr="8"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case -3: hoursStr="9"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case -2: hoursStr="10"; meridian = "PM"; break; 
                case -1: hoursStr="11"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case  0: hoursStr="12"; meridian = "AM"; break;
                case 12: hoursStr="12"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case 13: hoursStr="1"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case 14: hoursStr="2"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case 15: hoursStr="3"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case 16: hoursStr="4"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case 17: hoursStr="5"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case 18: hoursStr="6"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                case 19: hoursStr="7"; meridian = "PM"; break;
                default: hoursStr=String.valueOf(hours); meridian = "AM";
            }
            secondsStr=String.valueOf(seconds);
            minutesStr=String.valueOf(minutes);
            labelHours.setText(hoursStr);
            labelMinutes.setText((minutes<10) ? "0"+minutesStr:minutesStr);
            labelSeconds.setText((seconds<10) ? "0"+secondsStr:secondsStr);
            labelMeridian.setText(meridian);
        }
public void repeatClock(){
    display.timerExec( 10, repeat);
    }
}
```

I was experimenting with regions since that is what most of the similar questions I've been able to find have recommended, but it doesn't seem possible to place the labels in the transparent section.

Answer (score 0):

Since [4.5 M5 (search for 'transparent')](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/M5/), SWT supports controls with transparent background. If you set the controls background to *transparent*, the color of its parent will be visible.

```
label.setBackground( display.getSystemColor( SWT.COLOR_TRANSPARENT ) );
```

For more details see the corresponding [snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet365.java).

Comment: `SWT.COLOR_TRANSPARENT` doesn't seem to work for me at all. I just updated to Mars, would I need to redownload the SWT  library as well?

Comment: It all depends how you consume SWT, as a standalone jar? as a bundle? within an RCP application? What does `SWT.getVersion()` contain?

Comment: `SWT.getVersion()` outputs 4430 when i place it in a print statement. To download SWT I went to help >install new software in Eclipse itself

Comment: _Install new Software_ is the wrong place, it updates or installs new features in the IDE itslef. The SWT version should be about `4518` - the constant `COLOR_TRANSPARENT` must be defined in class `SWT`. Again, where does your current version of SWT come from?

Comment: I figured out how to use the newer version of `SWT`, but it seems that `COLOR_TRANSPARENT` doesn't work on `Shell`. What I am trying to do is have the numbers essentially be floating on top of nothing, rather than just having the background of the labels allow the shell background to show through.

Comment: If `COLOR_TRANSPARENT` does not work on `Shell`s you may want to have a look at the [emulate transparent shell snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet180.java).

Comment: Already looked at that. I really don't like the granulated appearance of the end product when using that. Also, i was hoping to find a way to do it with any arbitrary amount of alpha, rather than only one specific appearance that the snippet has. And it doesn't leave the label on top fully visible as it only appears on the grains and not the space between them.